# Response.redirect issue with rewritten URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, redirect, web

I am using a URL rewriter component (urlrewriter.net) and it's working fine. But, I am having issues with doing Response.Redirect from a rewritten URL. It is treating the rewritten URL as the actual URL you are on when doing the redirect. Is there a way I can tell it to do redirects relative to the location of the ASPX doing the processing?

E.g. Doing Response.Redirect("somewhere") from "www.domain.com/friendly/path/" (the actual  processing handler being "www.domain.com/handler.aspx") should take you to "www.domain.com/somewhere", not "www.domain.com/friendly/path/somewhere".

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `Response.Redirect("~/somewhere")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That takes me to the root of the site... I want to stay relative to the aspx.

Comment: do you have rules set for www.domain.com/somewhere redirection? did you map `~/somewhere` to `www.domain.com/friendly/path/somewhere` in your url rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes, I do have rules for www.domain.com/somewhere. In this example, it can be www.domain.com/somewhere.aspx... doesn't matter. I haven't mapped "/somewhere" to "www.domain.com/friendly/path/somewhere".

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to try full path to redirect from one page to another

for example to redirect "somewhere" instead of writing Response.Redirect("somewhere")
you have to write Response.Redirect(MailUrl + "somewhere") here MainUrl is url of site you can store that in web config file so that you can use.

try this.